# How take a link value to so many pages?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a link :

```
 <a href="All.php?city2=Newyork">Newyork</a>
```

And I have a value passed to that page:

```
 <?= $_GET['city2']; ?>
```

I have other pages such as All.php, Today.php, Tomorrow.php etc...

I want to take this value ('city2') to all pages, such as All.php, Today.php, Tomorrow.php etc... How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What does "take a value to" mean?

Comment: Store it as `$_SESSION['city2']`, http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: See I am taken "Newyork" to All.php. Ok. Like want to take this to all other pages mentioned above.?

Answer (score 1):

Store the `$_GET['city2']` in `session` variable, then you can get the value of `city2` in any page.

Something like this,

```
// start the session !
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION["city2"] = $_GET['city2'];
```

Now you can get the `city2` value in any page ,ex: `echo $_SESSION["city2"];`

Answer (score 0):

Set the city in a session in one page like:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['city2'])){
    $_session['city2'] = $_GET['city2'];
}
```

And then call the session in other pages like:

```
echo $_session['city2'];
```